# Explain these three things about #import in Objective-C: quotation marks, less than and greater than (<,>) symbols, and subdirectories

Tags: objective-c, import, operators

I want to archive my project but can't because of this nice little error (which leads down a futile rabbit hole in other searched questions and google group discussions): 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found.

The reason?  This little line (which happens to compile just fine even when building for the freakin' archiving):

```
#import "RestKit/RestKit.h"
```

Which makes me ask:

- **What do the quotation marks do compared to the < and > symbols?**  For example, I tried <RestKit/RestKit.h>.  It didn't work, but I don't know why.
- **What effect does the / have in the import?**  In my case, RestKit is located within an SDK in my project.  That puts it two tiers into my project (TopProj > SDK > RestKit in SDK).  How does the slash affect things?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @rmaddy.  I know you've removed XCode, but consider restoring it because the question also originated from the question of the structure of the projects included within projects in XCode.

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with Xcode. The same issue/question would apply if you were doing everything from the command-line. May I suggest that you read the details of the xcode tag  here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `< and >` In `#import` lines makes the preprocessor search for those files in system directories (`/usr/include`, etc. You can also define custom search paths in `Header Search Paths` under `Build Settings`). Use this for files like `UIKit/UIKit.h`, which is an Apple framework.
- This won't work for files added locally, for example, RestKit, which is why you instead use `"RestKit/RestKit.h"`, as that makes the preprocessor search locally for that file. This is for any file you create or add to your project.
- The slash in `"RestKit/RestKit.h"` is showing that the `RestKit.h` file is located in the `RestKit` directory.

Comment: Also note that in Xcode, for `#import` directives that use quotation marks, you can define custom search paths using the `User Header Search Paths` build setting. If you have some User Header Search Paths, then the `RestKit/` path does not have to be a subdirectory of the current source code file, it could be a subdirectory under one of the search paths defined in the build setting.